# Wordpress change login form text without access to the form itself

Tags: wordpress, forms, authentication

In WordPress, I'm trying to change the text of a login form without access to the form or shortcodes. Client site, theme's outside of support.
Basically I'm trying to change the form title text on this page
https://throughunity.org/login/  "Register as a single user" to "Register as a Unity Seeker" and simliar text in titles there.
I've tried multiple plugins with no success, and I suck at java.
Any help would be greatly appreciated folks.
(Thank You in advance)

Comment: I didn't understand well. You are trying to change this text without access the form? I mean, you do not have administrative access to the wordpress? Is that it?

Comment: Hi - replies to all here, I have WordPress admin access; your right, im not 100% confident in my php to do a core change correctly and knowing it goes away on theme update doesnt really appeal - Sorry! no offense.

Comment: I have wp admin access; I'm trying to change text on the login page throughunity.org . The form fields are not available to edit within WP. Or at least I cant find them after many trys and searches.The login form fields arent available to view/edit from within the wp adimn, as far as i can see -otherwise I'd use yelllowpencil~ If i could view the fields inside the admin panel Im sure icould edit, but - I cant, as its 'logged in' state when in admin. Corrections to form are for 'logged out' state/the logging in fields and te4xt of the form itself.

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to the underlying files, you should be able to edit the "wp-login.php" file directly (assuming you have a fairly standard WP configuration), though do be careful if you try to go this route and don't know what you're doing.  I would suggest searching this file for the text "Register as a single user" and replacing the text within the double quotes that you need to change.

If you don't have access to the underlying files, I think you'll have to provide a clearer explanation of what exactly it is you're trying to do and what you have access to.

Comment: If you ever need to change default functionality in WordPress, and you have to ask "Should I edit a core file to do this?" - The answer almost always an unequivocal **no**. This will lead to enormous headaches in the future, and require an effectively constant fork of WordPress to maintain. The appropriate thing to do is find a suitable Action Hook or Filter, and if none-exists, look at JavaScript or runtime solutions if necessary.

Comment: It sounds like Irishblake doesn't have confidence in his ability to solve this program appropriately using a proper approach. I agree that a custom filter or hook would by far be preferable and that editing the core plugin files is usually a bad idea that incurs a lot of technical debt. On the other hand, it might be a temporary solution he can live with enough until he can get to the point where he can implement a better solution or find someone who can do it for him.

Though I do note that an update of WP will overwrite this change, so as a suggestion, it should be used with caution.

Comment: I have wp admin access; I'm trying to change text on the login page throughunity.org . The form fields are not available to edit within WP. Or at least I cant find them after many trys and searches.The login form fields arent available to view/edit from within the wp adimn, as far as i can see -otherwise I'd use yelllowpencil~ If i could view the fields inside the admin panel Im sure icould edit, but - I cant, as its 'logged in' state when in admin. Corrections to form are for 'logged out' state/the logging in fields and te4xt of the form itself.

Comment: What theme are you using?